# Simplified rational distance problem

Tags: rational-numbers, pythagorean-triples

① Is there a point on a square with sides of rational length that is a rational distance from each vertex?

Note that this is a very specific case of the [Rational Distance Problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RationalDistanceProblem.html), which can be expressed more simply as:

② Are there any Pythagorean triples *(L, a, p)* and *(L, b, q)* such that *a + b = L*?

I've done a computer search for small values *(L < 2³¹)* and found these pairs of triples such that *a + b = L ± 1*, but none any closer:

```
+-----------+----+-----------+-----------+
|     L     |  ± |     a     |     b     |
+-----------+----+-----------+-----------+
|      1344 | -1 |       760 |       583 |
+-----------+----+-----------+-----------+
|      1600 | -1 |      1200 |       399 |
+-----------+----+-----------+-----------+
|      1508 | +1 |      1344 |       165 |
+-----------+----+-----------+-----------+
|     29040 | -1 |     28798 |       241 |
+-----------+----+-----------+-----------+
|    142912 | -1 |     82695 |     60216 |
+-----------+----+-----------+-----------+
|    594220 | -1 |    529371 |     64848 |
+-----------+----+-----------+-----------+
|   3751488 | +1 |   3049984 |    701505 |
+-----------+----+-----------+-----------+
|  17980480 | -1 |  10406328 |   7574151 |
+-----------+----+-----------+-----------+
|  40436800 | -1 |  30470799 |   9966000 |
+-----------+----+-----------+-----------+
|  65395616 | +1 |  34753887 |  30641730 |
+-----------+----+-----------+-----------+
|  95021927 | +1 |  87275664 |   7746264 |
+-----------+----+-----------+-----------+
| 189632508 | +1 | 168503165 |  21129344 |
+-----------+----+-----------+-----------+
| 234121100 | +1 | 208570992 |  25550109 |
+-----------+----+-----------+-----------+
| 283860000 | -1 | 182418750 | 101441249 |
+-----------+----+-----------+-----------+
| 513405900 | -1 | 395722000 | 117683899 |
+-----------+----+-----------+-----------+
```

Is there a simple disproof of ②?

Through elementary algebra, a precondition for ② is:

③ Are there non-trivial (i.e. distinct, strictly positive) integer solutions for *a² - b² = p² - q²*?

Which is equivalent to:

④ Are there non-trivial integer solutions for *a² + q² = b² + p²*?

Of which there are many examples, e.g. [Numbers that are Sums of Squares in Several Ways](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~mackay/sumsquares.pdf)

Comment: If I understand correctly your problem is unsolved.  See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RationalDistanceProblem.html

Comment: @jbuddenh - Note that this is a very specific case of the RDP. Do you think the general RDP can be reduced to this? i.e. If you prove or disprove this case, you prove or disprove the RDP?

Answer (score 1):

For 3, you can write it as $L^2=(a+b)(a-b)=(p+q)(p-q)$ so there are solutions for composite $L$.  To make $a,b,p,q$ integers requires that $L$ be odd or a multiple of $4$.  For example, $12^2=144=72\cdot 2=36\cdot 4=24 \cdot 6=37^2-35^2=20^2-16^2=15^2-9^2$  This doesn't get you 2, however.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in equating L² to those expressions. Have corrected.

Comment: It is true it is a precondition, not equivalent.  It is an easy precondition to meet, as shown in the paper linked under 4.  The Mathworld page you link to specifically says that item 1 is unsolved.

Answer (score 1):

See [The Mathematical Gazette, Volume 95, Issue 532, March 2011, pp. 59-61, *95.01 The rational distance problem*](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0025557200002333) by Roy Barbara. Quote:

> It is not known whether there is a point in the plane of a unit square, that
>   is at a rational distance from each of the four corners. See [1, 2, 3]. Here, we
>   give a negative answer for boundary points, using the non-existence of
>   particular Pythagorean triangles.